# JHipster :Removing a field from an entity: Liquibase does not remove the field from the database : Validation failed error

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

So I have a Jhipster entity that I am removing a field from using the command "Jhipster entity Model" for an entity I already have called Model
. It removes the field from the front end and java code, but the column is still in the database(h2 disk based) along with the data for each row in that field.

I get this error on startup of the spring app

```
 1 change sets check sum
      config/liquibase/changelog/20190411130704_added_entity_Model.xml::20190411130704-1::jhipster was: 7:03313fa12946fa4bb3e16f838f8dc4d7 but is now: 7:aed492b04b5a800b82655ff2eabd0f65


 liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
 1 change sets check sum
     config/liquibase/changelog/20190411130704_added_entity_Model.xml::20190411130704-1::jhipster was: 7:03313fa12946fa4bb3e16f838f8dc4d7 but is now: 7:aed492b04b5a800b82655ff2eabd0f65
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because your `changeSet` was changed after last liquibase execution, therefore, the checksum was changed.

To fix this, add `<validCheckSum>` tag to your `<changeSet>`.

As specified in the error, new checksum is `7:aed492b04b5a800b82655ff2eabd0f65`.

So add `<validCheckSum>7:aed492b04b5a800b82655ff2eabd0f65</validCheckSum>` to the changeSet.

Or add `<validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>`, but it's really a bad practice.

You shouldn't change the existing `changeSet` when you alter your database model. You should write another `changeSet` that removes the column, using proper `<preconditions>` and `<dropColumn>`.

E.g.:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="your_table" columnName="your_column"/>
    </preConditions>
    <dropColumn tableName="your_table" columnName="your_column"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: This seems like what I am looking for. Thanks alot. To be honest I was just going with what Jhipster did by default,not the greatest practice the way they do it then?

Comment: I’m not familiar with Jhipster, but looks like it.

Comment: Check JHipster doc about how to use Liquibase https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates